# can I set created_at and updatea_at by default?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible that the ORM set by default the created_at and the update_at in all models.

Currently I am using the following code in each model:

```
created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
```

But I want to know if is possible set any env variable to SQLAlchemy in order to avoid put this in each model.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/declarative_mixins.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible and you are already on the right track. A potential solution would be with minimal use of OOP, more precisely:

```py
class BaseTable(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)


class YourModel(BaseTable):
    # Your fields
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...


class AnotherModel(BaseTable):
    ...
```

So wherever you want to have the required two fields, you need to inherit the `BaseTable` class.

The [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-columns) is of course always the best reference to start with.